# java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No provider configured for S/MIME

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pkcs#12

I've been trying to solve my problem but I couldn't u_u

Well, let's see. I need to send an email (which I can do) but the last requirement was that I needed to attach a certificate (SSL) and that was the problem. This is my code:

```
        // @param _smimePw         keystore password = "techbrainwave"
    // @param _alias         keystore password = "certificatekey"

    // get the S/MIME EncryptionUtilities
    ##EncryptionUtils smimeUtils = EncryptionManager.getEncryptionUtils(EncryptionManager.SMIME);##

    // load the S/MIME keystore from the given file.
    char[] smimePw = new String("techbrainwave").toCharArray();
    EncryptionKeyManager smimeKeyMgr = smimeUtils.createKeyManager();
    smimeKeyMgr.loadPrivateKeystore(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\j2sdk1.4.2_18\\bin\\truststore.jks")), smimePw);

    // get our keys.
    java.security.Key smimeKey = smimeKeyMgr.getPrivateKey("certificatekey", smimePw);

    msg.setContent(parts);

    // write smime message.
    MimeMessage smimeSignedMsg = smimeUtils.signMessage(mailSession, msg, smimeKey);
    Transport tr = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    tr.connect(SMTPServer, "", "");
    smimeSignedMsg.saveChanges(); // don't forget this
    tr.sendMessage(smimeSignedMsg, smimeSignedMsg.getAllRecipients());
    tr.close();
```

The line that is marked is where the following exception brings my code down:

> java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No provider configured for S/MIME
>       at net.suberic.crypto.EncryptionManager.getEncryptionUtils(EncryptionManager.java:99)

I took the example from this link:

http://blog.jservlet.com/post/2008/01/03/How-to-use-Javamail-Crypto-with-S/MIME-provider?pub=0#pr

I hope you can help me please. I have two days with this problem and I don't know where the problem is. What I try to do is to attach a SSL certificate to my mail that is the resume of my problem. If there's another way to solve it I'll be grateful to see it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This error `java.security.NoSuchProviderException` means that no component was found that provides this service.
I am not sure if java's default providers actually do offer this. If you have already swapped to the unrestricted files my guess is that you need a third-party provider.
Use `Bouncy Castle` and by quick googling there is a [mention](http://osdir.com/ml/java.javamail.crypto-api.devel/2006-07/msg00002.html) of the following needed in your case (for a problem like yours):

```
javamail-crypto.jar  

javamail-crypto-bouncycastle-smime.jar  

and bouncy castle libraries.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception when I used the BouncyCastle libraries "..jdk15on-149.jar".
But with the older version "..jdk16-1.46.jar" it worked :)